# Methods for examining large/complicated lisp objects

Tags: hideshow, interactive-development

I've been working with some org export engine code which passes around some rather large and complex list objects.  It's rather tedious to explore an object by reading through a long word-wrapped printed representation of an object or iteratively writing and evaluating accessors in the scratch buffer.  I and am wondering if there are any good methods for interactively examining values.

Take for example: many IDE's that present object values in an interactive tree view which permits incrementally expanding keys/values.  The object is persistently shown on the screen and can be examined without much concern about the value types being viewed.  A random screenshot of Chrome developer tools as illustration:

[image: Chrome developer tools object view]

Other tools present values as navigable popovers (functionally very similar).  A random screenshot from Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio datatip]

Is there anything similar for emacs lisp?  Perhaps something built into edebug or provided by another package?  Or is this just waiting to be developed?

*Note: I discovered [pp](https://github.com/typester/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/pp.el) and [pp+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/pp+.el) shortly after posting this question.  The formatting is incredibly helpful in visually navigating object structure.  It saves needing to modify `print-length` and `print-depth` to extreme values and formatting the output in a separate buffer.*

Comment: Perhaps library [`hide-show.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) helps in this regard.

Comment: @ebpa If `pp` and `pp+` do what you want, then you can add that as your own solution and mark it as an answer in few days.

Comment: @Drew I provided an answer with the pp+-based solution.  I haven't been entirely satisfied with it though.  I'll update my answer when I publish a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function `pp-eval-last-sexp-with-tooltip` in the `pp+` package is a great general-purpose solution for this.  It is effectively the same as `eval-last-sexp`, but neatly formats the return value and displays it as a tooltip.  Values larger than `pp-max-tooltip-size` (`x-max-tooltip-size`) are shown in a separate window.

I have it bound to `C-x C-e` at the moment:

```
(require 'pp+)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-x C-e") #'pp-eval-last-sexp-with-tooltip)
```